# Upgrading Doorbell Transformer for Ring Doorbell Pro

Tags: wiring

I'm upgrading my Doorbell Transformer.  I already connected the house wire to the Transformer, but the doorbell wiring got me confused.

I have two white wires that I know will go together and Then I have one black wire.  Don't know which screw to connect it too on the diagram.  I see the two spots for the 16v which is the minimum and the two spots for the 24vac.

Which side does the white one go to and which side does the black go to?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what the arrows do. Look  at the voltage  you want. Follow the 2 arrows going away from it, which go to 2 terminals.  Those.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For my Ring Pro, I hooked one wire (the red) to the leftmost screw and the white wire to the rightmost for 24v. It's worked fine for a few years now.

Comment: It absolutely matters where the wires are connected , not all transformers are balanced as this one is not, this model is handy for building dual voltage power supplies of 5 &12v of the outside 2 at 24v

Comment: removed comment about side not mattering.

Answer (score -1):

The winding is split in this case but you need the 24v so use the outside 2.

This transformer has 3 voltages available left to center 8v right to center 16v and outside to outside 24v .

These are made so they have multiple uses.

**NOTE:** This is only a 20va transformer, I thought ring’s took more.

Comment: I don't know, 20VA is a lot for a small electronic device.   If a Ring actually used 20VA, it'd be warmer than ambient and glow red on a FLIR lol.

Comment: A simple google search shows: "Your Ring Video Doorbell Pro requires a power source that supplies a minimum of 16 volts AC at ~20 volt-amps when connected directly to a transformer, plug-in adapter, or ~30 volt-amps when used with an internal doorbell."

Comment: I have connected them on 24v 40va in the past when a chime was included 30 was insufficient but that may have been because of the chime unit.